# PHP __construct with unnamed function below

Tags: php, function, laravel, oop, laravel-5

I encountered this code in a larevel.

```
public function __construct(
    Request $request,
    UserRepository $userRepository,
    ProfileRepository $profileRepository
)

{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->request = $request;
    $this->profile_repository = $profileRepository;
    $this->model = $this->model_repository->getModel();
    $this->entity_name_plural = str_plural($this->entity_name);

}
```

What is the use of the unnamed function below the constructor? This is the first time I encountered this so I am not sure how it really works. Thanks for your response.

Comment: What do you mean? You only posted a single __construct() function, that takes three arguments (although they are on multiple lines) and then does some stuff. If you're referring to the parent call, that just means "call the constructor on the class this inherits from".

Comment: The method signature is separated from the method body by a line of whitespace.  There is no "unnamed function".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is just a bit strange formatted. It is just the constructor, you can probably recognise it better formatted like this:

```
public function __construct(Request $request, UserRepository $userRepository, ProfileRepository $profileRepository)
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->request = $request;
    $this->profile_repository = $profileRepository;
    $this->model = $this->model_repository->getModel();
    $this->entity_name_plural = str_plural($this->entity_name);

}
```

The line that reads `parent::__construct();` is calling the constructor of the parent class.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I was just confused with how it was formatted.

Comment: No problem, we are here to help. :)
Consider accepting an answer to be sure to get answers on future questions.

Answer (score 2):

```
parent::__construct();
```

This function calls construct method of your base controller. Which extending by you.

Answer (score 2):

***What is the use of the unnamed function below the constructor?***

The Class you are working on has a Parent Class from which it inherits some of its Properties & Behaviours (Methods). Alone; the current Class may not be able to do some Initial works necessary for a smooth Execution of your Program. And; **because of this PRE-INITIALIZATION - which is sometimes necessary**, the call:

```
parent::__construct();
```

implicitly tells the Parent Class: *Hey Dude!!! I am about to create [ __construct ] my own unique Objects, but first;  I'd need you to clear up the path for me and perform the necessary initializations before I step in....*  That is essentially more or less what that part says & does.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it in details.